# Kendo UI Validation for Duplicate Value Checking

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, kendo-ui

I am facing a problem with validation for duplicate value checking from server using json.
My code is runing fine in each click but error message show in second click(One click in side text box put value then click out side the text box - that time code execute but error message show . again i click in that text box and again click out side text box ,again my code run and this time error message show) . Please find my mistake and help me to show validation message in single escape or single click of  text box.

### script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"

//KendoUi Validation

```
    var validatable = $("#ApplicationNo").kendoValidator({
        onfocusout: true,
        onkeyup: true,
        rules: {
            ApplicationNo: function (input) {
                $.post("/Home/CheckAppNo", { ApplicationNo: $("#ApplicationNo").val() }, function (data) { b1 = data; })
                return b1;
            }

        },

        messages: {
            ApplicationNo: "Already Exist"
        }
    }).data("kendoValidator");

   var validatable = $(".k-content").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");
```

### C # Code

```
    public JsonResult CheckAppNo(string ApplicationNo)
    {
        bool IsOk = projectRepository.CheckAppNumber(ApplicationNo);
        return Json(IsOk, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        //return new JsonResult { Data = IsOk };
    }
```

### Html

> > < input type="text" id="ReferredBy" name="ReferredBy" class="k-textbox" required />

Comment: This is not question it is a solve of question How generate a dynamic dropdown in kendo ui

Answer (score -2):

I just add a line in JavaScript and run very well.

> $.ajaxSetup({ async: false });